# How to capture pop up close whose id is generated dynamically at creation time

Tags: jquery

How can i capture the closing of pop up event in this case ??

In our Application the id's that are  being generated for the **data-role="popup"** is dynamic which depends on item id's present in our database

So every item will have a unique ID as this case

transitionExample**101**
transitionExample**201**

At the creation time the itemid will be appended to the text transitionExample

In this case the how can i capture the close event of the popup ??

please see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/75/

If its static id i could have used simply used where transitionExample is the id

```
$(document).on('click', '#transitionExample-screen', function () {
    alert('closing');

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[attribute start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=transitionExample]', function () {
  alert('closing: '+this.id);
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Thanks a lot , i can start my logic with this .